# Simple one line 'Find/Replace' using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where I would like to find a specific string and then replace this string with a different string.

**Data**

```
ID           Date        Stat

AA101.aa     Q3 2022    AA101
AA101.aa     Q3 2022    aa
AA           Q4 2022    aa
BB           Q4 2022    bb
```

**Desired**

```
ID           Date        Stat

AA001.aa     Q3 2022    AA001
AA001.aa     Q3 2022    aa
AA           Q4 2022    aa
BB           Q4 2022    bb
```

**Doing**

```
df1 = df.replace(to_replace = "AA101” , value = “AA001”)
```

I keep getting syntax error, I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I think the quotation marks are the problem. Instead of `“`, use `"` or `'`.

Comment: thank you but it is still not replacing the strings that are 'AA101.aa' format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this

```
df.replace(regex=r'AA101', value='AA001')

 

       ID     Date   Stat
0  AA001.aa  Q3 2022  AA001
1  AA001.aa  Q3 2022     aa
2        AA  Q4 2022     aa
3        BB  Q4 2022     bb
```

Comment: thank you but how to update the values in column ID as well.

Comment: They appear to me to be an index. Are you able to provide code to create this df?

Comment: Because this work `df.reset_index().replace(regex=r'AA101', value='AA001').set_index('index')`

Comment: See my edits after you edited your df. It works

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `str.replace`.

You can either apply it for each column:

```
df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace('AA101', 'AA001'))
```

or `stack` the columns, use it; then `unstack` it:

```
df = df.stack().str.replace('AA101', 'AA001').unstack()
```

Output:

```
         ID     Date   Stat
0  AA001.aa  Q3 2022  AA001
1  AA001.aa  Q3 2022     aa
2        AA  Q4 2022     aa
3        BB  Q4 2022     bb
```

Comment: ok what does the stack do? does it alter the data in any way?

Comment: @Lynn It stacks the columns to create a Series object. `str.replace` is a Series method, so we can't use it on the DataFrame object itself. By stacking `df`, we're able to use it.

Comment: Please avoid apply, its is slow. stack should only be used if there is necessity. Readability and compute resource management part of good coding